# Create a reference (IBOutlet) from containerview to view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a view controller, which contains a containerview. I want to put a reference (IBOutlet) to the containerview in the view controller but when I click and drag I get the blue line but it doesn't allow me to place the reference.

Is there something special to do or am I missing something in my understanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you can only drag properties to the class which it belongs to.

So you can only drag properties to your containerViews controller and not the parent

Use property `parentViewController` as `self.parentViewController` and access all the properties you want.

Comment: I fixed it I was dragging from the view controller of the container, just needed to drag from the box that says containerview on the main view controller. Not really sure if thats what you were trying to say?

Comment: Yep. The same thing.